# my pipeline for auto devops in gitlab not working property

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab-ci-runner, docker-build, gitlab-autodevops

[this is my test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3y4ge.png)

**i run the job with autodevops runner**

i run this without .gitlab-ci.yaml file. but i receive the error like this.

```
$ if [[ -z "$CI_COMMIT_TAG" ]]; then # collapsed multi-line command
$ /build/build.sh
Building Heroku-based application using gliderlabs/herokuish docker image...
Attempting to pull a previously built image for use with --cache-from...
invalid reference format
invalid reference format
No previously cached image found. The docker build will proceed without using a cached image
invalid argument "/master:fa1708343b13496937aa567a1aecdc184f43d197" for "-t, --tag" flag: invalid reference format
See 'docker build --help'.
Cleaning up file based variables
30:00
ERROR: Job failed: command terminated with exit code 1
```

Comment: same here, could you solve it?